# Ember object of computed properties aliased to parent's properties

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember.js. I'd like to create an object X that has a property Y that is itself an object, which contains computed aliases to other properties of object X. However when I set object Y's aliases they reference object B's properties and not A's. Is there a way to do this?

```
Ember.Component.create({
  page: 1,
  templateData: Ember.Object.create({
    page: Ember.computed.readOnly('page') // I want this to reference the parent's page property
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot use `Ember.Component.create` as you are using computed
   properties.

   You must use `Ember.Component.extend` as stated in the [Ember API
   Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_create):

   > NOTE: For performance reasons, you cannot declare methods or computed properties during create. You should instead declare
   >   methods and computed properties when using extend or use the
   >   createWithMixins shorthand.
2. You must also use computed properties to create your `templateData`
   object:

   ```
   templateData:function(){
      return Ember.Object.create({
         page:this.get('page')
      });
   }.property('page')
   ```
3. Make sure that you want to create the `templateData` object as all of the
   properties of the component are available to the template.

Here is a [JSBIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zoqulebeje/1/edit)
Cheers!